# How to add a timestamp for when the Firebase object/node+subtree was modified?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to create a field for storing the timestamp of when the object was last changed. So if any of the object's properties (aka subtree) is modified, be able to set a timestamp field to the current time.

Firebase doesn't seem to have a way to keep track of when an object was last updated. Has anyone actually implemented a way to do this in an elegant fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily keep track of when a node was modified

```
root
  users
    some user stuff
  messages
    some messages
  places_to_eat
    some places to eat
  timestamps
    users: a timestamp
    messages: a timestamp
    places_to_eat: a timestamp
```

when data is written to the users node, update the [timestamps node](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency):

```
// iOS / ObjectiveC

Firebase *usersTimeStampsRef = [timeStampsRef childByAppendingValue:"users"];

[usersTimeStampsRef setValue:kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp];


// Android / Java

Firebase usersTimeStampsRef = usersTimeStampsRef.child("users");

usersTimeStampsRef.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

(you could just use timestamps/users as well)

Or, getting fancy, keep the timestamp within the node itself

```
root
   users
     timestamp: a timestamp
     user_list
       user_1
       user_2
```

I have a number of ObjC objects that are class objects to handle reading and writing of data and they automatically update the timestamp when modified.

So for example, I have a users class.

```
User aUser = [UserClass new]
[aUser createUser:"Jay"]
```

when the createUser method is called, inside the class it sets up the user and writes out the userName and updates the timeStamp accordingly. It's pretty seamless and low maintenance.

Actually, the parent class I created does the heavy lifting and writing of the timestamp so all of the subclasses that interact with Firebase inherit that functionality.

Comment: Nice, this was generally what I was imagining. Just kind of surprised that this seems to be the only way to do this. Would have thought Firebase keeps track of modification timestamps as part of its native implementation anyway

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? I've found a way to do it with a single parent class but it's not quite as straightforward as I imagined. For one, the firebase urls and keys have to be tracked through the superclass with my implementation.

Comment: I don't mind at all - however, it's MacOS ObjC code so it may not apply. There are a number of ways to go about this; you could create a singleton that keeps the path's or a reference to them. Or, when a subclass is created, init it with the type of thing that it is 'User' or 'Message'. Then, to create a user, init the object, pass it a user name (for example) and the the user class knows to create the user in the /users node and to update the /users/just_created_user_id/timestamp child to the current timestamp. Similarly, when updating the user name, the class will also update the timestamp.

Comment: @Jay Can you suggest a way by which I can track when the object was created (not modified)?

Comment: @EhteshamHasan Tracking when an object is created is the same pattern, just create a dictionary of the object you want to store with a  child node of 'created_timestamp:' and write your timestamp when the object is created. You may be asking something more in depth and if that's the case - please create a new question with details, code and a Firebase structure.